# Can't run XNA APP

Tags: c#, xna

i'm getting started with XNA game development and tried to run tutorail app on http://create.msdn.com/downloads/?id=753&filename=Shooter_Project_Windows.zip, but when i run, this blue window appears insted of emulator
[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: By the way, the fact that you have never *accepted* an answer to any of your questions will make it less likely that others will answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to know what is wrong for sure without more info.  The blue window you are seeing indicates that the project is running; it is just not displaying anything visible to you.

If I had to guess (and it's just a guess, but it's a common issue for these types of things), the issue is possibly that your camera is facing the wrong direction.  Other potential problems include things like the clip planes being set incorrectly.  You might also look at the console to see if something failed without crashing the program...if a mesh or something was supposed to be loaded, and failed for some reason, you might also not see anything.

Comment: A problem I had at first--I got the transparency backwards.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Ah, yes.  If you mean what I'm thinking, that you had polygons visible from only one side, and it was the wrong side, that is also a very common problem.

Comment: No, what I had was 100% transparent polygons--I interpreted the field backwards.  Of course I had backwards polygons that were sometimes a pain to figure out but once I got some drawing I understood about the backwards ones.

Comment: 1)How Can i check camera direction?